# 404 when trying to get index from Flask app running on nginx through uWSGI

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am trying to run a Flask application on nginx with uWSGI on my Ubuntu droplet following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04).

All the intermediate tests work fine until the very last one, where it's time to test all components working together.

Here is where the Flask app lives.

```
dsaltares@saltares:/home/dsaltares/conjugate/site: tree .
.
├── conjugate.ini
├── conjugate.py
├── conjugate.sock
├── wsgi.py
```

The relevant parts in `conjugate.py`
    bp = Blueprint('bp', **name**, template_folder='templates')

```
application = Flask(__name__)
application.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/conjugate'
application.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix='conjugate')

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The `wsgi.py` file

```
from conjugate import application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

The `conjugate.ini` file

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

socket = conjugate.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
uid = dsaltares
gid = www-data
```

Running `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w wsgi` works perfectly fine. I can access the app from my laptop.

The `/etc/init/conjugate.conf` file

```
description "uWSGI server instance configured to serve conjugate"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid dsaltares
setgid www-data

env PATH=/home/dsaltares/conjugate/env/bin
chdir /home/dsaltares/conjugate/site
exec uwsgi --ini conjugate.ini
```

Now the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file

```
server {
        listen 80;

        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        server_name example.com;

        location = / {
            # Redirect to /blog
            return 301 http://example.com/blog;
        }

        location /blog/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            ...
        }

        location /conjugate/ {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/home/dsaltares/conjugate/site/conjugate.sock;
        }
}
```

After `sudo service conjugate restart` and `sudo service nginx restart` and trying to access `http://example.com/conjugate` I get:

```
404 The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

`sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` doesn't show any errors.

Any ideas? Thank you very much

Comment: @DavidSaltaresMárquez Happy to hear it. Miguel (blueprints answer in the duplicate question) is actually the author of [an excellent book on Flask](http://flaskbook.com/). I highly recommend it, he has great suggestions for larger application structure. I usually define blueprints in separate packages, import their respective views in the blueprint `__init__.py`, then import / register them on the application on creation.

The companion code for Miguel's book has [a good example](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/app/__init__.py) of this method, using a factory function.